# problem with running pyqt(pyside) prorgram(exe)

Tags: python, memory, pyqt5, python-multithreading

I have the problem with converting pyqt code to exe file using pyinstaller

When I execture this code on terminal ( python test.py somthing like that) , code works fine.
(GUI starts and my program works)

But after I convert this code to exe file using pyinstaller, program / my computer freezes.
(GUI dose not start and error occurs (paging file is too small for this operation to complete)

I'm making exe file using spec file following this [documents](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html?highlight=spec)

When I check the process of exe file, it creates multiple processes as time passed.

**This is part of my code**

```
import numpy as np
from src import database as db
from src import backtest as bt
import sys
from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
                            QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
                            QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt, QPropertyAnimation, QEasingCurve, QEventLoop, QThread)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
                           QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon, QIntValidator,
                           QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
                           QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QMainWindow, QScrollArea, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem,
                               QLineEdit, QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QWidget, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect, QSizeGrip)
from PySide6.QtGui import QPainter
import PySide6.QtCharts as QtCharts

if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # If the application is run as a bundle, the PyInstaller bootloader
    # extends the sys module by a flag frozen=True and sets the app
    # path into variable _MEIPASS'.
    application_path = sys._MEIPASS
else:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))


class Thread(QThread):
    def run(self):
        QThread.sleep(3)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, app, parent=None):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        self.tableWidget = self.ui.tableWidget
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)

        # QSizeGrip(self.ui.size_grip_2)
        LineParamList = [self.ui.LineParam1, self.ui.LineParam2, self.ui.LineParam3,
                         self.ui.LineParam4, self.ui.LineParam5, self.ui.LineParam6,
                         self.ui.LineParam7, self.ui.LineParam8, self.ui.LineParam9,
                         self.ui.LineParam10, self.ui.LineParam11, self.ui.LineParam12,
                         self.ui.LineParam13, self.ui.LineParam14, self.ui.LineParam15,
                         self.ui.LineParam16, self.ui.LineParam17, self.ui.LineParam18]


        for LineParam in LineParamList:
            LineParam.setValidator(
                QIntValidator(0, 100, LineParam))
            LineParam.setText('0')


        self.df = db.make_sheet(application_path) #read dataframe from csv file
        self.config = db.read_config(application_path) #read dataframe from csv file

        self.ui.profit_table_button_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.profit_table_show())
        self.ui.run_button_2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.run())

        self.init_param()

        def moveWindow(e):
            if self.isMaximized() == False:
                if e.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
                    self.move(self.pos() + e.globalPos() - self.clickPosition)
                    self.clickPosition = e.globalPos()
                    e.accept()

        self.ui.header_frame_2.mouseMoveEvent = moveWindow

        self.thread = Thread()
        self.thread_init = Thread()

        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.ui.run_button_2)
        self.thread_init.finished.connect(lambda: self.init_param)
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.ui.LineParam1)


    def init_param(self):
        self.ui.LineParam1.textChanged.connect(
            lambda: self.changeSliderParam(self.ui.LineParam1.text(), self.ui.SliderParam1, 'param1'))


    def changeLineParam(self, value, interface, target='param1'):
        value = int(value)
        interface.setText(str(value))
        self.config['coef'][target] = value/100.

    def changeSliderParam(self, value, interface, target='param1'):
        value = int(value)
        interface.setValue(value)
        self.config['coef'][target] = value/100.

    def run(self):
        if not self.thread.isRunning():
            days, Profit, MarketProfit, accumProfit, accumMarketProfit, alpha, Volatility, CARG, SharpRatio = bt.RunBacktest(
                self.config, self.df.copy())
            self.create_profit_table(
                days, Profit, MarketProfit, alpha, accumProfit, accumMarketProfit)
            self.thread.start()

    def profit_table_show(self):
        self.ui.stackedWidget_2.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clickPosition = event.globalPos()

    def create_profit_table(self, days, Profit, MarketProfit, alpha, accumProfit, accumMarketProfit):
        # adding label to the layout
        days = list(days)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(alpha.shape[0])
        # plot window goes on right side, spanning 3 rows
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(days[:alpha.shape[0]])

        for idx in range(alpha.shape[0]):
            p = '{:0.2f}%'.format(Profit[idx]*100)
            mp = '{:0.2f}%'.format(MarketProfit[idx]*100)
            alp = '{:0.2f}%'.format(alpha[idx]*100)
            ap = '{:0.2f}%'.format(accumProfit[idx]*100)
            amp = '{:0.2f}%'.format(accumMarketProfit[idx]*100)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(
                0, idx, QTableWidgetItem(p))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(
                1, idx, QTableWidgetItem(mp))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(
                2, idx, QTableWidgetItem(alp))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(
                3, idx, QTableWidgetItem(ap))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(
                4, idx, QTableWidgetItem(amp))

        self.ui.profit_table_cont.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.ui.frame_22.setStyleSheet(u"background-color: transparent")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow(app)
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```